# Jade comments at the end of a tag

Tags: html, pug

I want to know if it's possible to put comments in jade at the end of an html tag, in the output file.

example:

```
<div class="header">
   ....
</div> <!-- ./this comment -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not a good idea.
But if you really want it, just add a comment after the div.
It won't be on the same line as the `</div>`.
It sends more html down the pipe, so I wouldn't recommend it for production use.

```
.header
    hello
//./header
```

If you use a `//-` comment, it will not make it into the browser's view source. Useful for private comments.